# Vs2010 Program runs in Debug mode but not in Release Mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-debugging, release-mode

I am trying to run a program in Visual Studio 2010. It uses filledShapes library and armadillo matrix library.

The code runs fine in debug mode but when i set it to release mode it hangs and tells me that I am missing  blas_win32_MT.dll files . But i have pasted this file in the debug folder of my solution and included the .lib files in the linker input.

Does anyone face the same problem

Comment: Do you think `when i set it to release mode` and `pasted this file in the debug folder` are related?

Comment: Yeah because VS tells me i am missing these files when i use release mode

Comment: that was meant a little sarcastically, I was basically asking if you added the linker input in the release mode configuration too.